# Adal AcquireTokenAsync how to know in advance if a user is in the cache

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I am working with Adal in a Xamarin application, and I would like to know how I can determine if a user is already in the cache before calling `AcquireTokenAsync`.

I need this because when the device has no internet, and there is no user in the cache, I will be redirected to the Azure login page, which will fail because of the lack of internet access.

In this scenario, when a user has logged in before losing the internet access the login will not be redirected to the Azure login page.

I want to avoid the ugly page when the internet is not available.

I already tried

```
AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/x.onmicrosoft.com");
return ac.TokenCache.Count;
```

But it is set to 0 until I call the `AcquireTokenAsync`, and after the call even when it does not ask for the user, the count is now 1

thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this example: https://blog.xamarin.com/put-adal-xamarin-forms/

```
authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Count()
```

Judging by the [source code](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/TokenCache.cs#L237), it calls the normal callbacks to load data, and then gives all the items back to you.

You can also try `AcquireTokenSilent`, it will throw `AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException` if it can't get a token from cache.